# Does Balanar (Nightstalker) also benefit from Luna's Eclipse?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Whenever *Luna* use her ultimate **Eclipse**, it turns night into day for a few seconds.

Does *Balanar(Nightstalker)* benefit from this? Or it's simply just an animation effects from Luna's spell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Night Stalker benefits equally from this false night as he does from a normal night or from his own ultimate.